# Is $C^1[a,b]$ a Banach space as a subspace of $C[a,b]$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $C[a,b]$ be the space of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ with the norm
$$
\left\Vert{f}\right\Vert=\max_{a \leq t \leq b}\left| f(t)\right|
$$

Then $C[a,b]$ is a Banach space.

Let's view $C^1[a,b]$ as a subspace of it. My question is, is this $C^1[a,b]$ a Banach space?

I think it is, since for every Cauchy sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $C^1[a,b]$, it is also a Cauchy sequence in $C[a,b]$, so it converges to a function $f$ in $C[a,b]$. But convergence in $C[a,b]$ is uniform, so $f$ is in $C[a,b]$ too, which follows that $C^1[a,b]$ is complete, i.e. a Banach space.

However, I just read a theorem named [Closed Graph Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem), stating that

> (Closed Graph Theorem) Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach space, and $T$ a closed linear operator from $A\subset X$ to $Y$. If $A$ is closed in $X$, then $T$ is continuous.

Apply this theorem to the above case, let $X=C^1[a,b]$, $Y=C[a,b]$ and $T=\frac{d}{dt}$ from $X$ to $Y$. We can prove that $T$ is a closed linear operator. Note that $X$ is closed in $X$, so by the above theorem $T$ is continuous.

However, it is easy to prove that differential operator is NOT continuous.

I am sure the Closed Graph Theorem and the last statement is true, so I think $C^1[a,b]$ is not Banach.

Could anyone tell me why?

Comment: The function $f$ may not be in $C^{1}[a,b]$. You can only garantee that $f\in C[a,b]$. you must use another norm to obtain completeness of $C^1[a,b]$. The right norm is $\|f\|=\sup_{[a,b]}|f(x)|+\sup_{[a,b]}|f'(x)|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
f_n(x)=\sqrt{x^2+\frac1{n^2}},\quad-1\le x\le1.
$$
$f_n\in C^1([-1,1])$ and converges uniformly to $f(x)=|x|$, but $f\not\in C^1([-1,1])$. This shows that $C^1([-1,1])$ is not complete with respect to the uniform norm.

$C^1([-1,1])$ is a normed space with the uniform norm, but bot a Banach space.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a subspace of a Banach space is closed if and only if it is complete if and only if it is a Banach subspace. Thus, and proper, dense subspace cannot be a Banach subspace.

Observe then, by the [Stone-Weierstrass Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), that the polynomials are dense in $C[a,b]$. In particular, $C^1[a,b]$ is dense in $C[a,b]$.